# How to host Clojure services in production

Tags: java, clojure, jetty

I have a Clojure REST service written in Clojure/Ring/Jetty. In development process I have ran them from command line `lein run serve`, but now I want to run them to production.

What is the correct way to do it ? In the .NET world I am using IIS (Internet Information Server) to host web applications. What do I need to use in the JVM ? Tomcat or any other servlet container ?

Comment: @nha My question is not about deployment and building. My question is about web servers and hosting. And I cannot find the answer in your link.

Comment: This is going to be opinion. Yes you can use Tomcat (a common solution) or any other servlet container but there is no _correct_ way to do it. The best option depends on a whole lot of factors that are outside the scope of your question.

Comment: @z7sgѪ Thanks, so  Ring application is a real servlet, right? And I can use any application server that can host servlets. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. You might find `lein-ring` useful to build wars. I have deployed them to production on Tomcat in the past, simply because that was the app server ops wanted to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I prefer to run clojure as standalone java applications. You can build an executable jar with `lein uberjar`. You cal take a look at this tutorial [uberjar](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#uberjar).

This will build you -standalone.jar. Than if you are in linux environment just run as following `nohup java -jar <projectname>-standalone.jar`